# does useFrame and zustand conflict with useState?

Tags: react-hooks, react-three-fiber, zustand

I have data retrieved from websocket sampled by default, every 2 seconds.
I propagate this data using zustand for state management.
I have multiple animations/components dependent on this data.
To compensate the 2 seconds interval gap I calculate what the data might be each frame which is not handled by zustand, but by useState.

I can use CustomEvent to update all the dependent components every frame or I can use a custom hook, i think, which i prefer.

The problem being that whenever the api > zustand > useStore updates local state (sample) of hook, useFrame loses local state.

Here's the hook ...

```
/**
 * merge two streams of similar data
 * one stream comes from api and has a default sample-rate of about 2 seconds
 * the second stream updates every frame change, roughly 60 frames / second
 */
export default () => {
  const { dc, status, metrics } = useStore((state) => state.api);
  const [sample, setSample] = useState(metrics.slice(-1)[0]);
  const advanceSample = (duration, sample) => {
    if (status === 'open') {
      const radiansPerSecond = (sample.rpm / 60) * 2 * Math.PI;
      const radiansPerFrame = radiansPerSecond * duration;
      const r = (sample.r + radiansPerFrame) % (2 * Math.PI);
      const active = degreesToActive[r * (180 / Math.PI)];
      return {
        ms: Date.now(),
        r,
        rpm: sample.rpm,
        c1: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) },
        c2: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) },
        c3: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) },
        c4: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) },
        c5: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) },
        c6: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) },
      };
    }
    return sample;
  };
  useFrame(({ clock }, delta) => setSample(advanceSample(delta, sample)));

  // const sampleEvent = new CustomEvent('sample', { detail: { sample } });
  // document.dispatchEvent(sampleEvent);
  return sample;
};
```

---

### the quick answer is no, neither useFrame, zustand nor React.useState conflict in this case

My solution was to update managed state, thru zustand, on every frame and propagate state via the state manager as follows ...
store method:

```
// increment state
next: (duration) => {
  const { dc, metrics } = get().api;
  const [sample] = metrics.slice(-1);
  const ms = Date.now();
  if (get().api.status === 'open') {
    const radiansPerSecond = (sample.rpm / 60) * 2 * Math.PI;
    const radiansPerFrame = radiansPerSecond * duration;
    const r = (sample.r + radiansPerFrame) % (2 * Math.PI);
    const active = activeCoilIndex[r * (180 / Math.PI)];
    set({
      api: {
        ...get().api,
        metrics: [
          ...get().api.metrics,
          {
            ms,
            r,
            rpm: sample.rpm,
            ...range(1, 6).reduce((accumulator, coil, index) => ({ ...accumulator, [`c${coil}`]: { mA: mA(active, dc), t: t(active, dc) } }), {}),
          },
        ].slice(-512),
      },
    });
  }
```

then within a separate component:

```
// increment state at generally 60fps
const nextSample = useStore((state) => state.api.next);
useFrame(({ clock }, delta) => nextSample(delta));
```

and finally propagation:

```
// use current state within each component as follows
const unsubscribe = useStore.subscribe(
  (metrics) => {
    const [sample] = metrics.slice(-1);
    if (crankshaftRef.current) crankshaftRef.current.rotation.z = sample.r;

    const sqrRodLength = Math.pow(rodLength, 2);
    const sqrCrankRadius = Math.pow(crankRadius, 2);
    const calcMotion = (offsetRotation) => {
      const radians = sample.r + offsetRotation;
      const cosR = Math.cos(radians);
      const sinR = Math.sin(radians);
      const displacement = crankRadius * cosR + Math.sqrt(sqrRodLength - sqrCrankRadius * Math.pow(sinR, 2));
      const moment = Math.asin(crankRadius / (rodLength / sinR)) * -1;
      return [displacement, moment];
    };

    if (conrod1Ref.current && plunger1Ref.current) {
      const [displacement, moment] = calcMotion(pistonsModels['piston1'].offsetRotation);
      conrod1Ref.current.position.x = displacement;
      conrod1Ref.current.rotation.z = moment;
      plunger1Ref.current.position.x = displacement;
    }
    ...
  },
  (state) => state.api.metrics
);
```

Comment: You should not be setting state in useFrame. Zustand has a subscribe callback which is better suited for this use-case. You want to update your state variable only when required and not 30+ times in a second

Comment: i was hoping for another solution that didn't require going thru the store, but gave it a try and it actually worked surprisingly well

Comment: actually on re-reading your comment, i see you've missed the question. I DO need to update state on every frame and have that state propagate to multiple components on different parts of the tree, re-composition is not possible either.

Comment: I have had issues previously while trying to update state in useFrame, it seems that react just ignores the changes when they happen that frequently. Also within react it is an anti pattern to change state in iterative functions such as render.
if you manage to make something work do let me know :)

Comment: as per above the data is used by four different components. The main component, the webgl engine, responds well and goes at 60fps, tho on additional components using the data the drop in fps is more noticeable with a drop of about 10fps to 50fps. Once it's running i'll post a sandbox with a backend mimicked engine and the websocket api to the webgl representation.